# Edit button in shortcode redirect to the page of the item from database Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a shortcode where I display some information from a form that was submited on another page. The question is how do I 'redirect' to the same form passing the id of the item that I press the button edit? Can someone give some advice

Here is the code for the shortcode:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'property';
$properties = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name");

?>
<?php foreach ($properties as $property) : ?>

    <div class="col-sm-4 my-4 card-selector">
        <div class="card bg-light text-dark card-height">
            <?php if ($property->sale_rent == 0) : ?>
                <div class="corner-ribbon top-left sticky red shadow">Sale</div>
            <?php elseif ($property->sale_rent == 1): ?>
                <div class="corner-ribbon top-left sticky red shadow">Rent</div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <img class="img-responsive card-img-top" src="" alt="">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h2 class="card-title"><?php echo $property->country ?></h2>
                <h3 class="card-title"><?php echo $property->price ?> £</h3>
                <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $property->county, $property->town ?></h5>
                <h6 class="card-title"><?php echo $property->displayable_address ?></h6>
                <i class="fas fa-bed"><?php echo $property->nr_of_bedrooms ?></i> <i
                        class="fas fa-bath"><?php echo $property->nr_of_bathrooms ?></i>
                <p id="description" class="description card-text"><?php echo $property->property_description ?></p>
                <?php if ($property->custom) : ?>
                    <a href="" class="card-link">Edit</a>
                    <a class="deleterow card-link"
                       href="">Delete</a>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

and here is a part of my form that I submited:

```
url: http://test.localhost/wordpress/add-property/
<h1>Add Property</h1>
<hr>
<div id="property-status"></div>
<form id="add-form" method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-8">
            <form name="contact-form" action="" method="post" id="contact-form">
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label>County*</label>
                    <input type="text" id="county" class="form-control" name="county" value="" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Country*</label>
                    <input type="text" id="country" class="form-control" name="country" value="" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Town</label>
                    <input type="text" id="town" class="form-control" name="town" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Postcode</label>
                    <input type="number" id="postcode" class="form-control" name="postcode" value="" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Description</label>
                    <textarea name="property_description" id="property_description" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
```

Comment: Can you point what variable contains the id and how you need to pass it - as a $_GET parameter ?

Comment: @IvnH I am asking how can I make the same form, to be also the edit form when I click edit, I know what should be in the value . I don't know how the url is compound . In php is ...?id=1. So my concern is  how can I redirect to the page with the url posted up with the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make your add and edit page same, you will need to add some more code in the add page.

First of all, make a change something like this

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url().'/add-property/?id='.$property->id;?>" class="card-link">Edit</a>
<a class="deleterow card-link" href="">Delete</a>
```

I am guessing `$property->id` is the primary key.
This way edit link will navigate to the same page when clicked.

Then, you will need to get the id in your add page at the top and fetch the data from database.

```
global $wpdb;
$id = $_GET['id'];
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'property';
$properties = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE property_id=$id");
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to do like this

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'property';
$properties = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name");

?>
<?php foreach ($properties as $property) : ?>

    <div class="col-sm-4 my-4 card-selector">
        <div class="card bg-light text-dark card-height">
            <?php if ($property->sale_rent == 0) : ?>
                <div class="corner-ribbon top-left sticky red shadow">Sale</div>
            <?php elseif ($property->sale_rent == 1): ?>
                <div class="corner-ribbon top-left sticky red shadow">Rent</div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <img class="img-responsive card-img-top" src="" alt="">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h2 class="card-title"><?php echo $property->country ?></h2>
                <h3 class="card-title"><?php echo $property->price ?> £</h3>
                <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $property->county, $property->town ?></h5>
                <h6 class="card-title"><?php echo $property->displayable_address ?></h6>
                <i class="fas fa-bed"><?php echo $property->nr_of_bedrooms ?></i> <i
                        class="fas fa-bath"><?php echo $property->nr_of_bathrooms ?></i>
                <p id="description" class="description card-text"><?php echo $property->property_description ?></p>
                <?php if ($property->custom) : ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo 'http://test.localhost/wordpress/add-property/?id='.$property->id;?> " class="card-link">Edit</a>
                    <a class="deleterow card-link"
                       href="">Delete</a>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>




<?php

global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'property';


if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $properties = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name where id= $_GET['id']");

    print_r($properties);
}

?>

<h1>Add Property</h1>
<hr>
<div id="property-status"></div>
<form id="add-form" method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-8">
            <form name="contact-form" action="" method="post" id="contact-form">
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label>County*</label>
                    <input type="text" id="county" class="form-control" name="county" value="" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Country*</label>
                    <input type="text" id="country" class="form-control" name="country" value="" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Town</label>
                    <input type="text" id="town" class="form-control" name="town" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Postcode</label>
                    <input type="number" id="postcode" class="form-control" name="postcode" value="" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Description</label>
                    <textarea name="property_description" id="property_description" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
            </form>
     </div>
</div>
```